# Dom Parser: Naming elements with accented (mainly Cyrillic) letters causes an error. (Java)

Tags: java, xml, dom

Is there a way to name an element name with accented letters in Java?

Answer (score 0):

That should work fine ***IF*** you express those letters in the encoding the parser expects. If the encoding isn't UTF8 or UTF16, make sure your document starts with an XML Declaration clearly stating what encoding you are using, and hope that the parser supports that encoding.

Comment: It is encoded in UTF-8. I suppose it is DOM that doesn't support it then. Thanks!

Comment: The DOM supports Unicode, unless you have a broken implementation of the DOM or the parser. If you told us which implementation you were using, and/or provided a sample document, and/or told us what the actual error message was, we might be able to give you more specific advice.